# Any suggestions on a way to get user comments back from a Xamarin Forms application. Possibly something using appcenter.ms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to add a "User Feedback" link to my Xamarin Forms application and I am looking for some suggestions on where to start.  If possible I don't want to have the user send me comments through email. I'm already using appcenter.ms and would like to use something like that or maybe there are web sites that users could use.

Would appreciate comments and suggestions on ways that this could be done.

Comment: https://github.com/alexrainman/ga-feedback/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let the user submit comments or feature requests via a few useful services:

1. zendesk and [their mobile sdk](https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/ios_support_sdk/nutshell)
2. intercom and [their mobile sdk](https://github.com/intercom/intercom-ios)

you can integrate support forms or feature requests, activate on user action in the app and communicate via corresponding services administrative part, which includes all the tools, charts, analytics and automation (alerts, bots, etc).

Answer (score 2):

https://instabug.com/platforms/xamarin

IOS Configuration

4- To start using Instabug in your iOS app, add the following line in the FinishedLaunching method inside the AppDelegate class.

```
Instabug.StartWithToken ("YOUR_APP_TOKEN_HERE", IBGInvocationEvent.Shake);
```

Android Configuration
5-To start using Instabug in your Android application, add the following line in the OnCreate method inside the **MainApplication** class.

```
new Instabug.Builder(this, YOUR_APP_TOKEN_HERE")
.SetInvocationEvent(InstabugInvocationEvent.Shake).Build();
```

https://ozaksut.com/how-to-integrate-instabug-for-your-xamarin-apps/